# ./src/index.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-dom/client' in "c:\users\....."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom, chokidar

[Above is the code of the index.js file, below is the error shown in this file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW2Og.png)

I have tried solving this error in many ways, I have also updated the React and React DOM to version
"react": "^18.0.0-rc.0",
"react-dom": "^18.0.0-rc.0". I also tried deleting the node modules and re-installing node modules. Waiting for solutions.  Also not able to understand these Chokidar errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing both react and react dom to latest stable v18 builds

```
npm i react@latest react-dom@latest
```

Additionally there's an error in your console about files being locked. Did you update the dependencies while the client was still running?

Comment: Thanks, Shlomo, it worked. I think I updated it while the client was running that's why there was an error. But now I updated after stopping the server and it worked.